# Access values from a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, node.js, web-deployment

Given below is the code to access and get values from a MySQL database using node.js. The file is `app.js`:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  database : 'dbname'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from table1', function(err, rows) {
  if (err) throw err;

  //console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  var arr=rows
  console.log(arr)
  respone.
});

connection.end();
```

The values that I am getting are stored in `arr`. How do I access these values on any web page?

Comment: you have to add the reference in your page so that you are able to access the array.

Comment: @user3217843 Add reference? I am a beginner so I don't know how to do that. Could you give some more details?

Comment: i hope you have a layout page or master page in your application.In that you have to add the path like <script scr="full path of app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @user3217843
And then the script will be executed every-time I open the page, yes?

Also, since execution of app.js requires the command `node app`, how do I make sure that I enter the command so that the script in app.js can be executed?

Answer (score 0):

It is just example for you. How you can use your code.

### app.js file

```
var http = require('http');
var mysqlquery = require('.\mysqlquery');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    mysqlquery(err, data){
        console.log(data); // your mssql data 
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World\n');
   }
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

### mysqlquery.js file

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    database : 'dbname'
});



module.exports = function(callback) {

    connection.connect();

    connection.query('SELECT * from table1', function(err, rows) {
       if (err) throw err;


       var arr=rows;
       callback(null, arr);
       connection.end();    
    });
}
```

Comment: On running the node server it shows:

    `mysqlquery(err, data){
                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3`